# How Can I Make Stylized Mountains Meshes Like These?

Tags: modeling, mesh, scene

I came across these images and a few others like them, and I love the way the mountains look. I'd like to create mountains like these in Blender, but I don't quite know how. They look simple enough, but I've never created anything like them before, so I don't know where to begin. Can anybody direct me if you know a way to do this (preferably the way they look in the first image)?

Thank you for the help!

[image: Photo 1]

[image: Photo 2]

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)